# TSQL Left Join: Show results regardless of match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have 3 tables, dbo.employees, dbo.cars, dbo.hours. I retrieve the three tables based on one another. dbo.mployees always has a row to be shown. dbo.cars sometimes does depending on employees, and dbo.hours sometimes does depending on cars.

```
SELECT          e.*, c.*, h.*
FROM            dbo.emploees e
LEFT JOIN       dbo.cars c ON e.id=c.employeeID
LEFT JOIN       dbo.hours h ON c.id=h.carID
WHERE           c.name='Honda City'
ORDER BY        e.id ASC;
```

I want to show all employees regardless. if there is a match on cars, show the car values, otherwise null values. if there is a match on huors, show them, otherwise null values.

The statement I have works great if there are matches on all three tables, when there aren't it displays nothing. No employees at all.

Comment: Works for me as well. Only way I got your result was when there were no employees without a car.

Comment: in my attempt to make it as pretty and simple as possible, i took out the where condition in the original post. I added it back in.

Comment: Well your attempt to make the query pretty made it in to a completely different query that did work!

Comment: Unfortunately not the one i need :(

Comment: Because of `WHERE c.name='Honda City'` predicate SQL Server will transform `LEFT JOIN dbo.cars c ...` into `INNER JOIN dbo.cars c`. So, SQL Server will execute: `SELECT ... FROM dbo.emploees e
INNER JOIN dbo.cars c .... LEFT JOIN ..`.

Answer (score 3):

There must be some other problems with your data cause your query is working perfectly fine. Please check here demo

**[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46d00/6)**

If you want to filter records for left join then you need to add condition on `join clause` like below. If you add filter condition in `where clause` then it will filter whole result, so it will not returns other employees whose car name is null. Condition in `where clause` is ok for `inner join`, but not for `left join`.

```
SELECT          e.*, c.*, h.*
FROM            dbo.employees e
LEFT JOIN       dbo.cars c ON e.id=c.employeeID AND c.name='Honda City'
LEFT JOIN       dbo.hours h ON c.id=h.carID
ORDER BY        e.id ASC;
```

Comment: U're right. I took out the "WHERE" condition (edited it again), I guess it is why it works. in your condition, if I was to add WHERE c.name='Honda City', it wouldn't show all employees. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.*, ch.*
FROM  dbo.employees e
LEFT JOIN       
(
Select c.*, h.*
From dbo.cars c
LEFT JOIN dbo.hours h ON c.id=h.carID
WHERE c.name='Honda City'
) ch 
ON e.id = ch.employeeID

ORDER BY e.id ASC;
```

As soon as you added the where clause all the employees with no car named Honda city got filtered out.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? Any employee with a car that isn't a Honda City will also be returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all employees who have either **no car** or a **Honda City** you will need to have the criteria in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT          e.*, c.*, h.*
FROM            dbo.emploees e
LEFT JOIN       dbo.cars c ON e.id=c.employeeID
LEFT JOIN       dbo.hours h ON c.id=h.carID
WHERE           c.name='Honda City' OR c.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY        e.id ASC;
```

If you want to show all employees (regardless of car type), and **only** show the car details and hours when the car is a **Honda City**, you should have the criteria in the JOIN clause:

```
SELECT          e.*, c.*, h.*
FROM            dbo.emploees e
LEFT JOIN       dbo.cars c ON e.id=c.employeeID AND c.name='Honda City'
LEFT JOIN       dbo.hours h ON c.id=h.carID
ORDER BY        e.id ASC;
```